# graphQL filter array containing ALL

Tags: graphql, strapi

I am quite new to graphQL, and after searching the whole afternoon, i didn't found my answer to a relative quite simple problem.

I have two objects in my strapi backend :

```
"travels": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Bolivia: La Paz y Salar de Uyuni",
        "travel_types": [
          {
            "name": "Culturales"
          },
          {
            "name": "Aventura"
          },
          {
            "name": "Ecoturismo"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Europa clásica 2020",
        "travel_types": [
          {
            "name": "Clasicas"
          },
          {
            "name": "Culturales"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

I am trying to get a filter where I search for travels containing ALL the user-selected travel_types.

I then wrote a query like that :

```graphql
query($where: JSON){
  travels (where:$where) {
    id # Or _id if you are using MongoDB
    title
    travel_types {name}
  }
```

And the parameter i try to input for testing :

```
{
  "where":{
    "travel_types.name_contains": ["Aventura"],
    "travel_types.name_contains": ["Clasicas"]
  }
}
```

This should return an empty array, because none of the travels have both Aventura and Clasicas travel-types.
But instead it returns the travel with id=2. It seems that only the second filter is taken.

I searched for a query which would be like **Array.every()** in javascript, but i wasn't able to find.

Does someone has an idea how to achieve this type of filtering ?

Thank you very much,

Comment: you wrote it as an  object, not as an array - wrong brackets, should be an array `[` of objects instead of one `{` - the same named object properties are overwritten

Comment: @xadm, sorry but i do not understand where I should have put the brackets ... I tried every possible way but I don't get it ...

```

Comment: array of objects ... `"where":[ { "travel`...}, {...} ]`

Comment: This gives me an error (Your filters contain a field '0.travel_types.name' that doesn't appear on your model definition nor it's relations") :

`{ "where":[  { "travel_types.name_contains": "Aventura" }, { "travel_types.name_contains": "Clasicas" } ] } `

Comment: sorry, I don't know what/how/if it is supported ... https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/3194

Comment: Thx for looking btw.
Yeah I looked into that topic and I wonder how &and and &or arn't implemented ... It's basic querying ... I'm sure there is a way but found it nowhere on the internet nor the documentations, ...

Comment: search and eventually open an issue on github?